# Can not get the element

Tags: javascript, html

Hello so when I try to get the **tbody** element in JavaScript I get the error that it is **null**
But whenever I use the **same method** to get the element but in a different file it works perfectly.

I have tried getting the element by id and class but nothing seems to be working.

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<table class="table table-striped" >
    <tbody>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my JS

```
    data_base.body.appendChild(tr);


        const data_base = {
            body: document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0],
        }
```

(UPDATE the problem was solved by adding the script to the bottom of the file)

Comment: Are you sure you're linking to the script in both files?

Comment: There's no element with the classname of "information" or "hiding" in the markup.

Comment: Yes, I have tried console.log and it worked

Comment: There are I have just not included them as they are not related to my issue

Comment: @BahramGozalov If they’re not related to your issue, then why have you included the `document.getElementsByClassName` calls that try to select these elements? [Edit] your post and provide a _[mre]_, please.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow bahram, please do make sure to have a tour on [ask] and [mcve], its quite unclear what you try to do here.

Comment: "_they are not related to my issue_" OK, what is then? Where exactly are you trying to access `tbody`?

Comment: `operation.setAttribute("click", "sitDown()");` makes no sense. You very likely mean `operation.addEventListener("click", sitDown);`.

Comment: Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/tBodies).

Comment: Make sure your script is not run before the elements exist.

Comment: Does someone know how to archive questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how u can get ur tbody element

```
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
```

so instead of

```
data_base.body.appendChild(tr);
```

use :

```
tbody.appendChild(tr);
```

by the way u can replace

```
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");

    const td_id = document.createElement("td");

    const td_name = document.createElement("td");

    const image = document.createElement("img");

    const td_image = document.createElement("td");

    td_image.appendChild(image);

    const td_price = document.createElement("td");

    const td_operation = document.createElement("td");

    const operation = document.createElement("button");

    td_operation.appendChild(operation);

    td_id.textContent = i;

    td_name.textContent = data_base.naming;

    image.src = data_base.url;

    image.alt = "Couldn't load image";

    td_price.textContent = data_base.price;

    operation.setAttribute("click", "sitDown()");



    tr.appendChild(td_id);
    tr.appendChild(td_name);
    tr.appendChild(td_image);
    tr.appendChild(td_price);
    tr.appendChild(td_operation);
    data_base.body.appendChild(tr);
```

with

```
const tr = document.createElement("tr");

tr.innerHTML = `
<td>${i}</td>
<td>${data_base.naming}</td>
<td><img src="${data_base.url}" alt="Couldn't load image"></td>
<td>${data_base.price}</td>
<td><button></button></td>
`;

data_base.body.append(tr);
```

to make your code more readable

and dont add an event listener as attribute as u did here

```
operation.setAttribute("click", "sitDown()");
```

Comment: So I get it from the array named "data_base". I have tried your method but it shows me that it is undefined

Comment: can u provide me with more details , show me the error exception??

Comment: script.js:106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
    at appendThis (script.js:106:15)
    at newTable (script.js:109:5)
    at giveMe (script.js:137:9)
    at script.js:141:1

Comment: @BahramGozalov Please add that error message to your question, it might prevent the question being closed.

Comment: so let me understand ur problem, u have data saved in localstorage and want to put them into ur table tbody isn't ? @BahramGozalov

Comment: The problem was fixed. It was all because I have linked the JS before the table

Comment: @BahramGozalov check out my edited solution to prevent more errors

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of `newTable()` you try to access the `<tbody>` with the line
`data_base.body`. However, that’s not [how accessing it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/tBodies).

Try changing the line to `data_base.tBodies[0]`.

Perhaps you’re thinking of [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body) for a property with the same name.

Comment: `data_base.body` seems to be defined somewhat correctly before calling the function.

Comment: The question was edited. Anyway, apparently a solution was found.

Comment: Indeed it was. Thanks for help!